# build dotnet solution in travis against netstandard20 and framework462

Tags: build, nunit, travis-ci, .net-standard

TLDR; I've got a mixed solution: NetStandard 2.0 for the library I'm actually developing and .Net Framework 4.6.2 (or alternatively dotnetcore 2.0) for the tests. How to configure travis.yml to build the library and the test project as well.

I'm actually working on a client for a rest api. I decided to use .NET Standard 2.0 as project type. As it is a REST based api, I decided to use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize and serialize the content.

A problem occurred: the nuget package Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3 doesn't support NetStandard 2.0 by now. But I found the commit ab3315f does. So I cloned the repo and build the netstandard library on my own as a workaraound till the new version is available in NuGet.

I added the project to CI system travis following this post: https://rimdev.io/building-net-core-on-travis-ci/

Now I added a test project to my solution using Nunit to run unit tests and integration tests for my library. No I'm facing 2 problems and I need to solve one:

problem 1: When my test project targets .NET Framework, I'm able to execute all the unit tests without any problems, but now travis complains based on my travis.yml there's no mono installed to build the complete solution correctly.
my question here: how to change my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/martinhey/WebUntisNet/blob/master/.travis.yml) to build both project types within the solution.

problem 2: When my test project targets dotnetcore, my local build works, but when I try to execute tests locally, I get a runtime error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

That's why I didn't test travis build by now, as I want to get it running locally first if this is the solution. I don't know why it doesn't find the dependency.

Any suggestions either for problem 1 or for problem 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding NuGet package of Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3 to my dotnetcore test project though it is not directly used there. Now the runtime error diappeared. So I am able to test locally and remotely as well and let travis CI build my project.

Comment: Do you use Package Reference or `packages.config`? To embrace .NET Standard, you should use the former plus all Microsoft latest tooling, such as VS 2017 15.4 and above. I have an example here, https://blog.lextudio.com/tips-for-net-core-unit-testing-92a8d123a17a though it uses xUnit.net.